# How to create Bottom Tab Bar that disappears on scroll in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm using React Navigation to create tab navigator in my app, what I want to do is  hide that tab bar when user scrolls down and bring it back again when user scroll to top again, Is there any cross-platform solution to that?

> **reference app is Linkedin**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have implemented component that show/hide Bottom Tab Bar. Based on the scroll direction param `showTabBar` is set.

```
 export default class ScrollTab extends React.Component {
  onScroll = (event) => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    const dif = currentOffset - (this.offset || 0);  

    if (dif < 0) {
      navigation.setParams({ showTabBar: true });
    } else {
      navigation.setParams({ showTabBar: false });
    }
    //console.log('dif=',dif);

    this.offset = currentOffset;
  }      

  render () {
    return (
      <ScrollView onScroll={(e) => this.onScroll(e)}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Then in `navigationOptions` it is possible to change `tabBarVisible` property  depending on the `showTabBar` param.

```
const isTabBarVisible = (navState) => {
  if (!navState) {
    return true;
  }
  let tabBarVisible = navState.routes[navState.index].params ? navState.routes[navState.index].params.showTabBar : true;
  return tabBarVisible;
}

const MessagesStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Messages: MessagesScreen,
  },
  config
);

MessagesStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    tabBarLabel: 'Messages',
    tabBarVisible: isTabBarVisible(navigation.state)
  }
};
```

Comment: I have already created it using a hack. But this one is a proper method and not a hack. Thank you

Comment: This will trigger many renders for the component. To mitigate this, only update navigation.setParams when the value is different

Comment: If you can avoid calling navigation.setParams all together, it would be much better. I had a tab bar where each tab has a stack of screens. I pass the tab navigation to the screen via extraData props like link below. I made sure to use a function for the onScroll and then just have that update the tab navigation tabBarVisible directly

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/#passing-additional-props

Comment: @baskInEminence Maybe try onMomentumEnd instead of onScroll

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: See [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/888#issuecomment-299600368) Github issue for the answer.

**Old answer**:
Based on a scrolling event from the Scroll View, you can set the [tabBarVisible](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#tabbarvisible) navigation option to false. If you want to have an animated smooth you could look into adjusting the height of the tabBar or moving the tabBar offscreen. I haven't tested any of this, but it would be the first thing I'd look into.

Comment: I have already tried that but seems like I can't set navigation options from class once they have been set

Comment: I want to implement the same with animation but tabBarVisibile is only hiding tab bar without animation. Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

```
I have implemented a custom ScrollView component that can be wrap inside any child component to achieve hide and show bottom functionality in react-navigation version 6+


<ScrollView
          
            onScroll={scroll}
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
            refreshControl={refreshControl ? refreshControl : undefined}
            {...props}>
            {children}
        </ScrollView>


And the scroll function will be something like this.

 const navigation = useNavigation()
    const parent = navigation.getParent();


    const onScroll = (event: any) => {
        const currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
        const dif = currentOffset - currentPos;
        if (currentOffset == 0) {
            parent?.setOptions({ tabBarStyle: { display: 'flex', animated: true } });
        }
        if (Math.abs(dif) < 3) {
        } else if (dif < 0) {
            parent?.setOptions({ tabBarStyle: { display: 'flex', animated: true } });
        } else {
            parent?.setOptions({ tabBarStyle: { display: 'none', animated: true } });
        }
        currentPos = currentOffset;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If your tab bar is a part of a native stack, then you can not acess showTabBar, what you can do in this case is just to toggle the display of the tab bar, if not, just use showTabBar